# How to set choices of field dynamically from foreign key related models field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-related-manager

I have models as `Offer` , `Wood` , `SliceTec` and `JointTec`. And `Wood` related with `SliceTec` and `JointTec` by M2M field. At Django admin I can select multiple options for **SliceTec** and **JointTec** when adding new Wood record. No problem. When it comes to Offer I need to show options from selected **Wood** records **woodSlice** data and also **woodJoint** data.

For ex;

SliceTec data: Slicet A, Slicet B, Slicet C

JointTec data: Jointt A, Jointt B, Jointt C

Wood data: Wood A , (Slicet A, Slicet C), (Jointt B, Jointt C)

At `Offer` I need to show **Slicet A** and **Slicet B** options when **Wood A** selected.

```py
class Offer(models.Model):
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Adınız Soyadınız')
    phone           = models.BigIntegerField(verbose_name='Telefon Numaranız')
    email           = models.EmailField(verbose_name='E-mail Adresiniz')
    date            = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Teklif Tarihi')
    frontWood       = models.ForeignKey('Wood', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    frontSlice      = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    frontJoint      = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    frontSupport    = models.ForeignKey('Support', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    frontThick      = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    frontDimen      = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    frontFlow       = models.ForeignKey('Flow', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    frontGlue       = models.ForeignKey('Glue', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name        = 'Teklif Talebi'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Teklif Talepleri'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Wood(models.Model):
    woodName    = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Ahşap Adı')
    woodCode    = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Stok Kodu', blank=True, null=True)
    woodSlice   = models.ManyToManyField('SliceTec', verbose_name='Uygun Kesim Teknikleri')
    woodJoint   = models.ManyToManyField('JointTec', verbose_name='Uygun Ekleme Teknikleri')
    woodImage   = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Görsel', blank=True, null=True)
    woodPrice   = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='Fiyat Düzeyi', blank=True, null=True)
    woodDesc    = models.TextField(verbose_name='Açıklama', blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name        = 'Ahşap Türü'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Ahşap Türleri'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.woodName

class SliceTec(models.Model):
    sliceName   = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Kesim Tekniği Adı')
    sliceImage  = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Görsel', blank=True, null=True)
    sliceDesc   = models.TextField(verbose_name='Açıklama', blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name        = 'Kesim Tekniği'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Kesim Teknikleri'
    def __str__(self):
            return self.sliceName

class JointTec(models.Model):
    jointName   = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Ekleme Tekniği Adı')
    jointImage  = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Görsel', blank=True, null=True)
    jointDesc   = models.TextField(verbose_name='Açıklama', blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name        = 'Ekleme Tekniği'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Ekleme Teknikleri'
    def __str__(self):
            return self.jointName
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are making single form, then, unless I'm missing something, there is no way to do this, since you don't know which wood is selected when you render the form.

You can try to implement logic inside the page using javascript

Comment: Thank you I think I have to try it on template

Answer (score 0):

You can change the labels in the admin with the following code.

Add this to your Wood model:

```
def description(self):
    slice_names = ','.join(self.woodSlice.values_list('sliceName', flat=True))
    joint_names = ','.join(self.woodJoint.values_list('jointName', flat=True))
    return '{}, (), ()'.format(self.woodName, slice_names, joint_names)
```

Then in the admin you can override the ComponentForm of your OfferAdmin

```
class OfferComponentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Offer
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OfferComponentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        id_dict = Wood.objects.in_bulk()
        current_choices = self.fields['frontWood'].choices
        new_choices = [(value, id_dict[value].description()) for value, label in current_choices]
        self.fields['frontWood'].choices = new_choices

@admin.register(Offer)
class OfferAdmin
    form = OfferComponentForm
    model = Offer
```

Comment: Got error;

Exception Type: AttributeError

Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute 'description'

Exception Location: C:\Users\egula\Desktop\ilkprojeler\okumalistesi\panelbuilder\admin.py in <listcomp>, line 22

Comment: Of course, I am sorry. Value is only a reference to a Wood object. I fixed the code by adding an `id_dict` that holds pairs {wood_id (int): wood_object (Wood)} and calling the description through that. `description` was also missing the brackets which I added